# Replacing a single varible works, how do I replace every occurance of a tag?

Tags: php, mysql, template-engine

So i made a basic template system for a project my company is developing. Currently I am able to load a template and print it out, and use a tag we developed to call templates within another template by calling `<template::>template_name<::/template>` in the master template. This works awesome as long as I only call ONE template. After the first occurance of the template tag, the system stops and doesn't go on to read the rest of the string from the database to get possible other template tags.

If i call the SAME template multiple times in the script, it will render right, but if I call a NEW template, it gets ignored by the system and gets printed as a normal text.

Here is my current functions for calling the tags and replacing them:

```
$inject_template = $this->get_template_name_between($template, "<template::>", "<::/template>");
if(!empty($inject_template)) {
    $query_for_template = "SELECT * FROM ".$field." WHERE templateid = '".$inject_template."' LIMIT 1";
    $injected_template_data = $wms->function->query($query_for_template);
    while($returned = mysql_fetch_array($injected_template_data)) {
        $type = $returned['templatetype'];
    }
    $template = str_replace('<template::>'.$inject_template.'<::/template>', $this->injectTemplate($inject_template, $type), $template);
}

public function injectTemplate($template_id, $template_number_type) {
    return $this->extract_template($template_id, $template_number_type);
}

public function get_template_name_between($string, $start, $end) {
    $ini = strpos($string, $start);
    if($ini == 0) return '';
    $ini += strlen($start);
    $len = strpos($string, $end, $ini) - $ini;
    return substr($string, $ini, $len);
}
```

Remember, this works if I call ONE tag, I simply need a way to force the function to replace ALL the tags with the right template for each. I was thinking maybe a for loop, and counting, but not sure the correct syntax to do that and I've been staring at this all day now lol. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try using `preg_replace_callback()`. It will replace all matches for the regular expression, and you can provide a callback function that looks up the replacement based on the template name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a loop that keeps replacing until there are no templates in the string.

```
while ($inject_template = $this->get_template_name_between($template, "<template::>", "<::/template>")) {
    $query_for_template = "SELECT * FROM ".$field." WHERE templateid = '".$inject_template."' LIMIT 1";
    $injected_template_data = $wms->function->query($query_for_template);
    $returned = mysql_fetch_array($injected_template_data);
    $type = $returned ? $returned['templatetype'] : '';
    $template = str_replace('<template::>'.$inject_template.'<::/template>', $this->injectTemplate($inject_template, $type), $template);
}
```

You don't need to use a `while()` loop around `mysql_fetch_array()`, since the query is limited to 1 row.

BTW, you should stop using the `mysql_*` functions. Convert to `mysqli` or `PDO`, and use prepared queries.

Comment: Thank you so much. This fixed the issue perfectly. I was using the `mysql_*` functions because of the backwards compatibility and the development server isn't running a very recent version on php or mysql, bur we will look into switching.. thanks

Comment: mysqli works with PHP 5.0.7 and newer. PDO comes with PHP 5.1 and newer. Backward compatibility shouldn't be an issue.